# Blurred Navigation Bar with same background as UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to achieve a similar effect to that of the Notes app on iOS in that I have a tableView with a background image and I want the navigation bar to have the same background image but without the text from the tableView overlapping.
[image: Tableview with background image]

Here is the tableView scrolled. As you can see, the text of the tableView overlaps that of the status bar and navigation bar. That is why I want the blur effect on the navigation bar.[image]

Comment: Ios7 or 8? If 8 only then there is a very easy way to do this.

Comment: ^ @savner that doesn't answer my question. Also I'm using iOS 7 for now but will do 8 as soon as it comes out.

Comment: @Fogmeister what is the iOS 8 way

Comment: I can't remember the name but ios 8 has a class called something like transparency view or something. It picks up the background and blurs it automatically.

Comment: Link, or can u post an answer? @Fogmeister

Comment: @jamespick did you ever find a solution to this?  Would love to hear an answer...

Comment: @inks2002 use a UITableView inside a UIViewController and turn off automatically adjust scroll insets.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS8 there is a new `UIView` subclass called [`UIVisualEffectView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIVisualEffectView/initWithEffect:).

You instantiate it with...

```
UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]; // other styles available
```

or...

```
UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIVibrancyEffect notificationCenterVibrancyEffect]; // other styles available
```

You then can do one of two things.

Either add this in front of the views you want to show through. (Not a sub view but in front of the content).

Or you can take a view and set it as the `contentView` of the `visualEffectView`.

This will then automatically add the effect to the content. It even updates when the content is updated so if you have something animating behind it it will show the blurred animation for you.

Comment: How should I implement this into a Navigation Bar